# Cyclohexane replacement in Food Chemical Analysis

Tags: cyclohexane

We have to use cyclohexane in the laboratory for the chemical analysis of olive oil in the UV spectrometry. But it's highly toxic for respiration.

Can anyone suggest a chemical to replace cyclohexane but which is safer to use the same in the UV spectrometer?

Comment: Cyclohexane isn't "highly toxic". It's just a cycloalkane, hardly different from fuel you got in a car.

Comment: Most of solvents are more toxic than non-aromatic hydrocarbons.

Answer (score 2):

Cyclohexane ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclohexane) reports a boiling point of $\pu{80.74 ^\circ{}C}$ presumably at ambient pressure) is not this much toxic that a single accidental inhale will kill you -- but did you consider to i) close the optical cell with a lid (if lost, get in touch with a manufacturer), and ii) do you work in a well aerated lab?
[image]

(image credit [fireflysci.com](https://www.fireflysci.com/micro-spectrophotometer-cuvettes/type-18-standard-micro-cuvette-with-ptfe-cover-lightpaths-5-100mm))

Though more often seen in labs working with dusty samples, there are dust extractors one can join to the exhaust pipes of a lab; these «umbrellas» can be adjusted in height and position over other equipment without obstruction of the lab bench (not a replacement for fume hood):

[image]

(image credit to [labtechsupplyco.com](https://www.labtechsupplyco.com/lab-furniture/fume-extraction-systems/))

One may think about [n-heptane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptane), with a boiling point reported with $\pu{98.38 ^\circ{}C}$, similar to the one of water.  However, each substitution of the solvent can open complications.  For one, the solubility of the analyte(s) may change, and the position of the absorption bands (keyword [solvatochromism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvatochromism)).  At what level are these changes *chemically* significant?  Only the collection of new reference data and calibration curves can answer this.

Chemistry aside, if the analysis is required by local law, the intended swap *can* constitute leaving the official protocol your lab got the accreditation for, and invalidate the results of the analysis *legally*.  But perhaps your customers do agree that you use a different protocol recognized by a body like FDA, ISO, ASTM, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most organic solvents are inhalation hazards; that is no reason to be paranoid about using them carefully.  Cyclohexane is low in toxicity. Bulk use of solvents should be in a fume hood or in a sealed system with a condenser. Samples for uv-vis analysis should be in well stoppered cuvets to prevent evaporation. Cyclohexane seems to be useful as the solvent to measure olive oil pigments in the visible and near uv. It can be obtained pure the only contaminant a trace of benzene that absorbs near 270nm. Cyclohexane must dissolve all the common components of olive oil and is volatile enough to be removed by careful distillation under slight vacuum. A substitute for work further in the uv where benzene might interfere would be n-hexane.